# How to compare multiple condition in if statement java?

Tags: java, math, expression, calculator

I am new to java and I'm trying to create a basic calculator with additional functionalities such as Square, square root etc. 
I am using an if-else logic for the input from user. 
the logic is somewhat like this:

```
                           Expression
                 --------------------------------
                |                                |
            if expression(+,-,*,/)              else if expression (sqrt, sqr)  
                |                                |
            take 2 inputs & execute switch      take one input and execute
            statements                          java math functions
```

I'm stuck with the if statement where I need to compare the expression with the (+-*/)operators. 
Can anyone guide me to implement this? Any other suggestion to improve the logic is also welcome.

Comment: Hey! Please share the code you are stuck with and explain what you are stuck at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Switch(String) - cases` to map to particular code and you case use `ScriptEngineManager` which comes inbuilt with JDK1.6 to eval a simple math string

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class MathCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the expression : ");
        String expresion = scan.nextLine();

        double a, b;
        double result = 0;

        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        switch (expresion) {
            case "+":
            case "-":
            case "/":
            case "*":
                a = scan.nextDouble();
                b = scan.nextDouble();
                result = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(engine.eval(a + expresion + b)));
                break;
            case "sqrt":
                a = scan.nextDouble();
                result =  Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(engine.eval("Math.sqrt("+a+")")));
                break;
            case "sqr":
                a = scan.nextDouble();
//                result = Math.pow(a,2);
                result =  Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(engine.eval(a + "*" + a)));
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to work. however i'm sure it's not the right way to code

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello Dan! Welcome to your basic calculator");
    Scanner usrInput = new Scanner(System.in); // for usr inputs

    double input1, input2;  //for usr i/p 1,2 and result

    double result = 0; 

    System.out.println("what\'d you like to perform? (*,/,-,+, ^(sqrt), 2(square)");
    char mathOperator = usrInput.next().charAt(0); // for math operation

    if (mathOperator == '+' || mathOperator == '-' || mathOperator == '*' || mathOperator == '/') {
        System.out.print("enter first number: ");
        input1 =  usrInput.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("enter second number: ");
        input2 = usrInput.nextDouble();

        switch(mathOperator)
        {
        case '*':
            result = input1*input2;
            break;

        case '/':
            result = input1/input2;
            break;

        case '+':
            result = input1+input2;
            break;

        case '-':
            result = input1-input2;
            break;
        }

    } else if (mathOperator == '^' || mathOperator == '2') {

        System.out.print("enter number: ");
        input1 =  usrInput.nextDouble();

        switch(mathOperator)
        {
        case '^':  // sqrt
            result = Math.sqrt(input1);
            break;

        case '2':
            result = input1*input1;
            break;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid operator");
    }

    usrInput.close();       
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

}